# Triple venn diagram shading

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Today in class we were asked to shade the regions of a triple venn diagram where the rules applied. Two of the questions stumped me as I wasn't sure how to handle the mixture and priority of the rule. 
These were the two questions:

Shade the regions:

1) $(A' \cap B') \cup C$

2) $(A \cap B) \cup C$

Would you be able to display on a venn diagram example showing how to do these?

Comment: Remember that intersection "$\cap$" corresponds to **and**; union "$\cup$" corresponds to **or**.

Comment: @Rohan: ***PLEASE*** don't go on retagging benders after deciding that a new tag is needed without some input from the community first. Namely, wait a few days and let people decide if this is a good idea for a tag. You *should* speed things up by opening a meta thread. ([In recent memory](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27492/limit-for-number-of-questions-where-tag-can-be-added-by-tag-creator-soon-after-t).)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry sir. Will definitely do as per your suggestion.

Comment: @Rohan: In case you missed it, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27601/

Answer (score 0):

For number 1: [diagram1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28complement+A+intersect+complement+B%29+union+C).

For number 2: [diagram2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28A+intersect+B%29+union+C).

I would recommend trying to figure out how to draw these diagrams before you look at the answers.  They are not very difficult, just make sure you have pencil and eraser handy.